# impossible to design a quantum circuit that uses ‘black box ’ U to implement the controlled unitary CU

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-control

I am supposed to show that it is impossible to design a quantum circuit that uses the ‘black box ’gate U to implement the controlled unitary CU .

I have been given the following hint: Find a unitary U such that CU and C(−U ) behave differently.

Does anybody have an idea? I wasn't able to find such a U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try controlled-$S$? i.e.
$$
U=S=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix}.
$$

If I act controlled-$S$ on $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, it produces
$(|00\rangle+i|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, while if I act controlled-$-S$, I get $(|00\rangle-i|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. These two states are orthogonal, so I'd be able to tell which I had. However, there should be no way of distinguishing if you have a unitary $U$ or $-U$.

In fact, *any* unitary that you pick will work. To see this, calculate the inner product of the outputs of the two gates acting on an input state $|\psi\rangle$. You get
$$
\langle\psi|c-(-U)^\dagger\cdot c-U|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi| c-(-U^\dagger U)|\psi\rangle.
$$
Since $U$ is unitary, $U^\dagger U=I$. controlled-($-I$) is just another way of saying "apply $Z$ to the control qubit". Hence, and state for which $Z\otimes I$ maps it to an orthogonal state (such as the one I picked) will do.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply!

Wouldn't the scalar product of $(| 00\rangle + |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and  $(| 00\rangle -i |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ be $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)$?

Also, what is the c in the equation? I don't really get that, I'm sorry.

Comment: The c is what I'm using as shorthand for controlled- (i.e. $c-U$ is the controlled-$U$.

Comment: Why would you be taking the inner product of $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ and $|00\rangle+i|11\rangle$?

Comment: Wouldn't you check whether two states are orthogonal by computing their inner product and checking whether it is zero?

Comment: you're interested in whether the two states that are output by the action of either c-$U$ or c-$(-U)$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Ah, i computed the output of CU wrongly, I forgot the i ^^. Now it makes sense. Now, to make sure I get it, the idea here is that if we give our circuit (CU / C(-U))the above written state $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, we can distinguish whether we used $U$ or $-U$ (by e.g. checking whether the output is orthogonal to $(|00\rangle+i|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, but in a normal circuit of $U$,$-U$ we wouldn't be able to do that because $\langle U\Phi | -U\Phi\rangle = \langle\Phi|-\Phi\rangle = -\langle \Phi|\Phi\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)